# Is Django AuthenticationForm authenticating with is_valid()?

Tags: django, django-forms

When I use `AuthenticationForm` in my login view, I find that when I check `form.is_valid()`, it returns `False` if the user creds are incorrect. I thought that `is_valid()` checks validity based on the form class's validation criteria and not by actually doing a database query. Am I incorrect?

For examples here's a simple login view:

```
def login_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"Welcome back {request.user.first_name}.")
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Why is this not returned for invalid creds?")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "This is returned for invalid creds.")
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

`form.is_valid()` returns `False` if I enter a proper email and password for a non-existent account. I would think that it would return `True`, and `user` would be `None` when we `authenticate()`.

Is `is_valid()` authenticating the user credentials? Please provide a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does try to `authenticate`.  Here is what it tests:

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
                                       password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                code='invalid_login',
                params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
            )
        else:
            self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

    return self.cleaned_data
```